# What is the most efficient inverse of lodash _.intersection()

Tags: javascript, lodash

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), I want to find all the elements between two arrays that are different, basically the opposite or inverse of [_.intersection[with|by]](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersection). Of course I reviewed [_.difference[with|by]](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference) but it's not an inverse version of _.intersection as it only compares the first array with the second, rather than comparing them against each other. The closest I was able to get is very cludgy which has motivated me to ask here if I'm missing a more efficient and/or elegant option. I'm only interested in lodash based solutions.

Here is the closest I could come up with to get a unique array of values that are different between both arrays. I'm interested in values with `id` properties that aren't in both arrays and values with matching `id` properties but different `v` properties.

```
const n = [{id: 0, v: 9.7}, {id: 1, v: 1.7}, {id: 3, v: 2.6}, {id: 4, v: 1.89}]
const o = [{id: 1, v: 1.7}, {id: 3, v: 3.6}, {id: 7, v: 0.89}, {id: 4, v: 1.89}]

_.uniqBy(_.concat(
    _.differenceWith(n, o, _.isEqual), _.differenceWith(o, n, _.isEqual)), 'id')
```

That code will yield:

```
[{id: 0, v: 9.7}, {id: 3, v: 2.6}, {id: 7, v: 0.89}]
```

Comment: how did you decided to keep between these two `{id: 3, v: 3.6}` and `{id: 3, v: 2.6}`?

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A the ```v``` property is different

Comment: I mean how did you decided to keep `2.6` not `3.6` in the output

Comment: Ah, I see. Actually I don't care, I'm only interested in the fact they are different.

Comment: Is it the coronavirus that's responsible for lack of activity or is my question boring or irrelevant?

Comment: in my opinion the question is somehow vague, the expected output is unclear ( even-though u said that code will yield ... ) is it the output u want, or is it the the output of that code and u want to fix it; also the "only lodash" solution will reduce the response rate significantly; since understanding the suggested solution u provide require lots of mental overhead ( which could be fixed by providing a simple snippet :) and **no** corona had increased the activity as far as I see.

Comment: the best possible runtime is `nlog(n)`

Answer (score 2):

[_.xorWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xorWith) is the closest I could think of, but it doesn't work with the example you provided because two objects have an `id` of 3.

```
const n = [{id: 0, v: 9.7}, {id: 1, v: 1.7}, {id: 3, v: 2.6}, {id: 4, v: 1.89}]
const o = [{id: 1, v: 1.7}, {id: 3, v: 3.6}, {id: 7, v: 0.89}, {id: 4, v: 1.89}]
_.xorWith(n, o, _.isEqual)
```

output would be:

```
[
  { id: 0, v: 9.7 },
  { id: 3, v: 2.6 },
  { id: 3, v: 3.6 },
  { id: 7, v: 0.89 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question after looking for the same thing, but I since came to realize that for my use case - identifying records that don't match, and then why they don't match - it isn't useful to have a list of all differences like that.

That list can't tell me anything I can use, so I would still need to do a further operation to see which array/s are the problem.

So for me, it makes more sense to first check for equality, then to use `_.difference` twice, because then the result of it yields usable information, e.g.

```
if (!_.isEqual(a, b) {
  const idsFromBThatAreNotInA = _.difference(a, b);
  const idsFromAThatAreNotInB = _.difference(b, a);
}
```

I don't know what the use case of the OP is, so I don't know if this is directly relevant, but maybe it can help others.